# Need help with "if" in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hi to every 1 need your help with "if" in Flash AS3, it should be like this:

> **if sound play go to frame 1 and if sound doesn't play go to frame 2**

```
if (SoundMixer.soundTransform=new SoundTransform(1);)
{
gotoAndStop(1);
}else{
gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

how to make it work, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `==` for equality comparison.  `=` is an assignment operator.

```
if (SoundMixer.soundTransform == new SoundTransform(1)) {
    gotoAndStop(1);
} else {
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

See [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html) for more.